# Change iOS Device Date

Tags: uiwebview, calendar, uidatepicker

I have a `UIWebView` that displays a date for an oriental calendar. If i go into settings and change my device date, then reload the app, the `UIWebView` date also changes. My question is, is there a way to select a date through the `UIDatePicker` and it changes the device date so the `WebView` can load a different date.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API that allows a 3rd party app to change the system date on a non-jailbroken iOS device.

You can certainly let a user pick a date and show a calendar for the chosen date but the display can't be based off of the system date. You would need to pass the chosen date to the URL shown in the web view.